# convert rtmp streaming to rtsp and http streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, red5, rtmp

i was installed red5 server on ubuntu 12.04 lts for live and vod video streaming. i just want to convert my `RTMP` protocol stream to `RTSP` and `HTTP` protocol stream. i was studied and search about `FFMPEG`. but i did not understand correctly. so please guide me any one. thanks advance

the sample URL

```
rtmp://xxxxx.com/live
```

to

`rtsp://xxxxx.com/live`   and  `http://xxxxx.com/live`

Comment: i know wowza server can handle re encoding rtmp stream to rtsp, but you may have better luck in the red5 forums.

Comment: i know that also. because wowza have default settings. i want to do with open source

Answer (score 0):

There are red5 plugins for hls(http live streaming) and rtsp. I don't know how stable they are so you can try. Here are the links.

https://github.com/Red5/red5-plugins/tree/master/rtspplugin

https://github.com/Red5/red5-hls-plugin

Comment: The rtsp plugin needs a lot of work, which I haven't had time for nor a sponsor. We have a new project demo for rtsp to flash https://github.com/Red5/red5-rtsp-restreamer

Answer (score 0):

You could write a transcoding application that uses Xuggler and converts your streams on-the-fly to RTSP (RTMP -> RTSP). That isn't meant to sound simple, but it can be done as well as the other way around (RTSP -> RTMP).